# Rate of convergence for the sign of sample mean

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, mean

What is the rate of convergence for $\textrm{sign}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i})$? ( $X_{i}$ are independent and identically distributed as $F$ satisfying the conditions for central limit theorem)

Comment: Why should it converge? Take for instance the case when the mean of the $X_i$'s is zero.

Comment: @Xi'an is right--but if the mean of $F$ is nonzero, then the sign does converge and its rate of convergence is easily derived from the CLT.

Comment: @whuber  I read a paper which says this rate of convergence is faster than root n, but cannot see how. Can you provide more details on how to find its exact rate based on CLT?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, this sign in the population is assumed nonzero. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu<0$, with $\text{var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$, then
\begin{align}\mathbb P(\bar X_n \ge 0)&=\mathbb P(\bar X_n \ge \mu-\sqrt{n}\mu\sigma/\sqrt{n}\sigma)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(\bar X_n \ge \mu-\frac{\sqrt{n}\mu}{\sigma}\underbrace{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}_{\text{sd}(\bar X_n)}\right)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\{\bar X_n - \mu\} \ge -\frac{\sqrt{n}\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
&\le -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}\mu}\dfrac{\exp\{-[\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma]^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\qquad\text{for the Normal cdf, with $\mu<0$}\\
&=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}\mu}\dfrac{\exp\{-n\mu^2/2\sigma^2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\end{align}
So the rate of $\text{sign}(\bar X_n)$ *not* going to the right value is of order
$$\exp\{-n\mu^2/2\sigma^2\}/\sqrt{n}$$
Note that the bound
$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\{\bar X_n - \mu\} \ge -\frac{\sqrt{n}\mu}{\sigma}\right)\le -\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}\mu}\dfrac{\exp\{-[\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma]^2/2\}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
[can be obtained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function#Bounds_and_approximations) as
$$\mathbb P(X\ge x) =\int_x^\infty\phi(u)\,\text{d}u <\int_x^\infty\frac ux\phi(u)\,\text{d}u =\int_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty\frac{e^{-v}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\text{d}v=-\biggl.\frac{e^{-v}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}\biggr|_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty=\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$$
when $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful and completely clarified my confusion.

Comment: How do you obtain the inequality on the third line?

Comment: @whuber That's by tail probability bound for standard normal distribution.

Comment: @TD888 I recognize that: but the standard Normal is only *approximating* the distribution of the standardized $\bar X_n,$ so quoting an approximation for the tail probability (Mills Ratio) is irrelevant unless one can also show that the standard Normal approximation is *at least as good* as Mills Ratio--and I don't see why that's generally the case.

Comment: I'm still baffled Xi'an, because this answer seems to assume $X$ has a Normal distribution, whereas the question assumes only that it has some arbitrary distribution function $F$ with finite second moment.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, I indeed gave the answer under the Normality assumption and have no clue on extending it to the general case. Since$$\mathbb P(X>0)$$ is asymptotically equivalent to$$\Phi(-\sqrt{n}\mu/\sigma)$$this should work for a larger number of cases, but I dunno under which conditions.

Comment: After looking around a bit, it seems it would apply under [Cramér's condition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cram%c3%a9r_theorem), namely the existence of a moment generating function.

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks for the extra comments. One question:  as far as I understand, as long as $F$ satisfies the standard conditions for Central Limit Theorem (like finite mean and variance), the bound you provided should be (asymptotically) valid. Since an asymptotically valid bound for the error probability is all we want here, it seems that the problem is completely solved. My question is: Why do we need to talk about the Cramer's condition here? is the Cramer's condition weaker than the standard conditions for Central Limit Theorem but still gives asymptotic normality? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this goes beyond my expertise. And probabilist colleagues I contacted have no clear answer either.